# Do I need SSL certificate for my website to get info for my iphone app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, database, ssl

I am working on iPhone app with NSURLConnection api. I created Login/Signup screens and just realized something missing with my website server that I didn't have SSL certificate yet for secure personal info.

I am wondering if you ever need to have SSL certificate for your website server for your iPhone app to get HTTP request for your login/signup. My app doesn't have any payment info just only username/email/password info. I just want to make sure all those infos will be stored in a secure way. Please let me know if I need SSL certificate or not. Any suggestion appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: If you don't secure and it gets sent plaintext, your accounts could be hijacked and worse, if the user uses the same password for things like Facebook, you could have serious egg on your face.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mix talk of storage and transmission in the same sentence but they are separate things and the SSL has got nothing to do with storage of items on the iOS device.

If you transmit the information using HTTP it will be unencrypted and anybody can read it.

In order to encrypt it you have to send it using HTTPS, which requires a certificate.

This will only encrypt the data, it won't prove to your device that the server is who it says it is. Even if you are using HTTPS/certifcates there is no guarantee that the server is who he says he is UNLESS you additionally validate that certificate in your handset code. If you want good reference material for this see the book "iOS 5 Programming Pushing The Limits".

As for secure storage of data on the client that's an entirely different matter (the quick and easy answer that everybody says is use keychains, however if you're serious about security I recommend reading the book "Hacking and Securing iOS Applications" to realize just how insecure data on the iPhone can be.).

Answer (score 2):

No you don't *need* to, but it is recommended as otherwise, the credentials will be sent in cleartext.